# Spring MVC- display value in JSP only if request parameter was passed

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I want to create a JSP page where user can select a value from a dropdown, submit it and see results on the same page. I don't know how I can achieve this. 
Here's the JSP page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Station choosing view</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Select the station</h1>
    <form:form commandName="station" action="archive.htm" method="get" >
        <form:select path="id">
            <form:options items="${stations}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="localisation"></form:options>
        </form:select>
        <p><form:button>Submit</form:button></p>
    </form:form>

    <c:if test="${foundStation.id!=null}">
        <p>Station code is ${foundStation.code}</p>
    </c:if>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the code of a controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/archive", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView readingHistory(@RequestParam (value = "id", required = false) Long stationId){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("archive");
    Iterable<Station> stationList = stationDAO.findAll();
    modelAndView.addObject("stations", stationList);
    modelAndView.addObject("station", new Station());

    if (stationDAO.exists(stationId)){
        modelAndView.addObject("foundStation", stationDAO.findOne(stationId));
    }

    return modelAndView;
}
```

How can I avoid printing the contents of `foundStation` if the `id` parameter is not passed while accessing the page? I think I'm using `<c:if test>` in the wrong way. The above code works as expected when the `id` parameter is passed.

The error I get is:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: The given id must not be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I avoid printing the contents of foundStation if the id
>   parameter is not passed while accessing the page?

The ff. code will throw a `NullPointerException` if `foundStation` is `null`. So accessing the `id` attribute won't be possible.

```
<c:if test="${foundStation.id!=null}">
```

Change that to:

```
<c:if test="${foundStation != null}">
```

Also, make sure to do a null check first on your `stationId` parameter before call methods from the Repository. This should prevent the error you got from occurring.

```
if (stationId != null) {
    if (stationDAO.exists(stationId)){
        modelAndView.addObject("foundStation", stationDAO.findOne(stationId));
    }   
}
```

Comment: That did not change anything.

Comment: I believe the error you got is not related to the `<c:if>` tag issue in your JSP.  Try the updated code I'll be posting.